# How can I validate a html form with images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I tried coloring the input field and I succeeded, but when I try to do it with an image the browser doesn't display it.

validate with color (ok)

```
    input:required:invalid,
    input:focus:invalid
    {
      background-color:#ffb9b9;
    }

    input:required:valid
    {
      background-color:#adf3c9 ;
    }
```

I tried this with image but it dosnt works:

```
input:required:invalid,
input:focus:invalid
{
 background-image: url(/images/form_validation.png);
 background-position: right bottom;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input:required:valid
{
 background-image: url(/images/form_validation.png);
 background-position: right top;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: It should work with no problem. Have you checked the location of the images?

Comment: @idfurw yes, i checked several times the location, it's correct. the browser does not return any position errors

Comment: I think you should find 404 error or something like in the DevTools Network panel.

Answer (score 0):

It should work.
I'm guessing the image path is not correct

Here's minimal example. (I am using svg but it should work with any image)

```css
input:required:invalid,
input:focus:invalid
{
  /* background-color:#ffb9b9; */
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='red' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM5.354 4.646a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708L7.293 8l-2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708L8 8.707l2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L8.707 8l2.647-2.646a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8 7.293 5.354 4.646z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top right;
}

input:required:valid
{
  /* background-color:#adf3c9  */;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='green' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-3.97-3.03a.75.75 0 0 0-1.08.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-.01-1.05z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top right;
}
```

```html
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" id="email" value="example@example.com" required>
<hr>
<label for="confirm-email">Confirm Email</label>
<input type="email" id="confirm-email" required>
```